# Should i mock useEffect also, if i test useState mock?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have test which checking useState call on mouse enter and mouse leave

```
    test('should update state on mouse enter and mouse leave', () => {
      const setStateMock = jest.fn()
      const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState') as jest.Mock
      useStateSpy.mockImplementation((init) => [init, setStateMock])

      point.simulate('mouseenter')
      expect(setStateMock).toBeCalledTimes(1)
      expect(setStateMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true)

      point.simulate('mouseleave')
      expect(setStateMock).toBeCalledTimes(2)
      expect(setStateMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false)
    })
```

i always get TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined for useEffect or sometimes write that hooks order has changed. Value of useState hook also is in useEffect dependencies. Should i mock useEffect or maybe i have different error?

Comment: Yes. Or you probably shouldn't mock neither of them. Messing with framework internals places additional responsibility to make it work the same way as original implementation, which is natural for authors of third-party testing libraries like Enzyme but isn't something that regular devs that write tests are ready for. If you're unable to ensure this, you end up testing not agains React but something else. Functional components are currently tested by their behaviour and not implementation, commonly with React Testing Library.